# Curl Get request response is not right

Tags: curl, get, response

Curl Get request response is within the url parameters. Below is the code.

```
    $url = "?data=$data&product_key=$this->product_key";
        return $this->Connect('GET', 'creditcomplete' . $url);


    public function Connect($requestMethod, $entity, $body = null) {

            $curl = curl_init(BASE_API_URL . 'v1/' . $entity);
            $options = array(
                'Apikey: ' . api_key . '',
                'Token: ' . token . '',
                'Secret: ' . secret . '',
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Accept: application/json'
            );

            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $options);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $requestMethod);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

            if ($requestMethod == 'POST' || $requestMethod == 'PUT') {
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
            }

            $curlResponse = curl_exec($curl);

            if($this->isJSON($curlResponse)) {
                $curlResponse = json_decode($curlResponse, 1);
            }       

            curl_close($curl);

            return $curlResponse;
    }

    private function isJSON($string) {
        return is_string($string) && is_object(json_decode($string)) ? true : false;
    }
```

Response is:

```
creditcomplete{"Response": {"Reminders": [],"Repayments": [],"Payouts": [],"Transactions": []}}
```

I don't know why creditcomplete is adding with the response. Any help will be appreciated. PHP version 7.1.23.

Comment: What api are you calling? Perhaps it has something to do with the api.

Comment: it's not with the api, the api is working fine on another development platform and on server too but may be something wrong with my system/PHP configuration. which i don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Check $options variable. Are api_key, token, secret constants?

Comment: yes, they are constant. authentication is working fine. response have data but is not in proper formate. the creditComplete is extra which i don't know from where is adding in the start.